# Как получить цифру из href кнопки таба, к которому относится контейнер таба?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <li href="#tab-1">tab1</li>
  <li href="#tab-2">tab2</li>
  <li href="#tab-3">tab3</li>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content"><button>получить цифру из href таба(1)</button></div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"><button>получить цифру из href таба(2)</button></div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"><button>получить цифру из href таба(3)</button></div>
</div>
<!-- как получить цифру из href кнопки таба, к которому относится контейнер таба? -->
```

Можно ли как-то средствами js или jquery получить это число? При чем для каждой кнопки, потому как они лежат каждая в своем контейнере таба, получить нужное число из атрибута href кнопки таба.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
(function(){
  $(function(){
    $('button', '.content').click(function(){
      var href = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id')
      var n = $('[href=' + href + ']').attr('href').replace('#tab-','')
      console.log(n)
    })
  })
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs">
  <li href="#tab-1">tab1</li>
  <li href="#tab-2">tab2</li>
  <li href="#tab-3">tab3</li>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content"><button>получить цифру из href таба(1)</button></div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content"><button>получить цифру из href таба(2)</button></div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content"><button>получить цифру из href таба(3)</button></div>
</div>
<!-- как получить цифру из href кнопки таба, к которому относится контейнер таба? -->
```

Comment: А почему сразу `id` дива не обработать? Код короче же будет.

Comment: только хотел добавить в описание, просто привел пример цепочки, в данном случае, если жестко заданы идентификаторы можно и так и так.

Comment: @Anamnian вопрос же про получение из href

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev верно, но зачем усложнять жизнь себе и автору? Когда мы может указать на данный недочет.

Comment: это одна строка кода в любых вариантах, вообще не вижу сложности

Comment: @Anamnian, автор еще неделю будет думать почему у него ссылки не работают ;) упрощая вы его только запутаете

Comment: сначала хотел написать без привязки к идентификаторам вообще, поиск по индексу, универсально типа))), потом думаю нет...